# Flot graph animation possible?

Tags: animation, graph, charts, flot

Is it possible to animate flot graph similar to this "www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barLineAnimated.html"??

How to add animations for the below code?

```
$("#verticlebar").width($('#verticlebar').parent().width());

$.plot(chartID,chartData,options);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with this plugin (Flot Animator) : http://www.codicode.com/demo/flotanimator

I developed this plugin, it can animate any type of series type (lines, bars, points), you can choose the animation direction (left, right, center), the duration, steps..

Answer (score 1):

Not in the core library, but Juergen Marsch has created some plugins that animate certain plot types.  There's a [demo](http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/grow.html) available, and you can find the source on his [downloads page](http://jumflot.jumware.com/Experimental/Download.html).

Comment: @sp2358234 You should either contact the author of the plugin, or open a separate question with more details about what's happening.